# Have marker edges pass through each other in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib, with the regular plot function, can I make my markers have their edges pass through each other, and not stack as in the image shown?

[image]

Comment: you'd have to either omit the face color so that the marker is truly hollow, or set the markers (face + edge) to be partially transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt option to separate the marker's facecolor from the edge. Hence, in order to make the marker edges apparent one would draw two plots, one for the faces and on top of that, one for the edges.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(32)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(30)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(30))

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(5.5,2))

## plot
ax.plot(x,y, marker="s", ms=15, color="C3")
ax.plot(x,y, marker="s", ms=15, color="none", mec="black")

## scatter
ax2.scatter(x,y, marker="s", s=15**2, facecolor="C3")
ax2.scatter(x,y, marker="s", s=15**2, facecolor="none", edgecolor="black")


ax.set_title("plot")
ax2.set_title("scatter")
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In addition, you can also set the alpha of the facecolor so that each marker is partially transparent.